# WPF bind textblock to two item sources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to bind a TextBlock to two different sources.  Basically the user selects an item from a datagrid that populates some TextBoxes and some TextBlocks. Then user can edit things and select from a listbox. I need the TextBlock to be update from the datagrid on selection then if the user changes something in the listbox the TextBlock is updated at that point.

Comment: this is now the point to learn MVVM http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx

Comment: Make a property in your ViewModel and databind it to that TextBox and then you are free to do whatever you want (combine strings from multiple sources etc.)